# How to make specific links change color when hovering over?

Tags: html, hyperlink, dreamweaver

I was told about a:hover {}, but the problem is that it gives these settings to all the link in the page, whereas I only want links with a specific CSS style to do that. Is there a way to put the a:hover setting in another class? Anything can be of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.class:hover {}
```

Pretty much this. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/9SfaG/

Comment: Thank you very much Kaloyan Ivanov :D I'm new to HTML (learning it in university) and am not quite familiar with how it works. You helped me with my assignment :-D

Comment: Good to know. :) You could accept the answer by clicking the white check to the left if it was helpful to you :3

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
a.myclass:hover {}
```

and use it like this

```
<a href="my/url.html" class="myclass">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a.class1:hover {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">test1</a>
    <a href="#" class="class1">test2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href=/url/ class="speciallink">link</a>
```

in css:

```
a.speciallink {
    option: value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo-classes and CSS Classes**

Pseudo-classes can be combined with CSS classes:

```
a.red:hover {color:#FF0000;}

<a class="red" href="css_syntax.asp">CSS Syntax</a>
```

If you hover over the link in the example, it will be displayed in red.

From http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp